# what is container1 and container2 in product view page in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, product, layout, products-view

I need to know what  is this container1 and container2 in magento product view page. i am talking about the file `view.phtml` in the location `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/catalog/product/view.phtml`

**upadate question:**

I have asked this question because.. I came to know  that, these sections are responsible for displaying the options in the product view page.

Actually my problem is I have 3 bundle product and I want to display their custom  options in my own phtml file. I have these codes with me..

```
<?php
$id=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku(123456);
$prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$x=$prod->getOptions();
foreach($x as $y)
 {
echo $y->getTitle();
print_r($y->getValues());
}
?>
```

I need to get the product through it's sku.That is why I coded like this.now I am getting the title correctly. but there values not displaying.(note: I added two dropdown options as my custom options)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you go with this @rajeevktomy?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

These relate to the position in which the product's custom options are displayed.

See `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml`:

```
<design>
    <options_container>
        <option1 translate="label">
            <value>container1</value>
            <label>Product Info Column</label>
        </option1>
        <option2 translate="label">
            <value>container2</value>
            <label>Block after Info Column</label>
        </option2>
    </options_container>
</design>
```

Here you can see that `container1` relates to 'Product Info Column', while container2 is 'Block after Info Column'. These values are describing where the custom options will be displayed on the product view page. You can set these values when editing a product in the Magento admin under the Design tab.

The layout blocks are defined in `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml`:

```
 <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container1" as="container1">
    <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container1</value></action>
    <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
</block>
<block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container2" as="container2">
    <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container2</value></action>
    <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
</block>
```

And in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` you will see two calls:

`<?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>`
and
`<?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>`

Comment: sorry I forgot to accept it :-)

Answer (score -4):

You can edit phtml file go to the below path
app/design/frontend/themename/default/template/catalog/product/info/container2.p‌​html
OR
if it is downloadable product 
app/design/frontend/themename/default/template/catalog/downloadable/catalog/product/links.phtml